# Creating alias and script alias in Apache

Tags: 12.04, apache2

I am configuring LG looking glass on Ubuntu. I have followed  [this link](https://github.com/Cougar/lg). In step 3 they said to add following two lines to webserver config:

```
Alias /lg/favicon.ico /usr/local/httpd/htdocs/lg/favicon.ico
ScriptAlias /lg /usr/local/httpd/htdocs/lg/lg.cgi
```

I have added it to my webserver config:

```
#vi /etc/apache2/sites-available/default

Alias /lg/favicon.ico "/usr/local/httpd/htdocs/lg/favicon.ico"
    <Directory "/usr/local/httpd/htdocs/lg/favicon.ico">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

ScriptAlias /lg/  "/usr/local/httpd/htdocs/lg/lg.cgi"
        <Directory "/usr/local/httpd/htdocs/lg/lg.cgi">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128

        </Directory>
```

When I tried `http://127.0.0.1/lg` in my browser, it shows `not found`.

I am new with web-server, can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, you have only added aliases for /lg/favicon.ico and /lg/lg.cgi, and not the lg directory itself. Try pointing you browser to one of these files, or changing your configuration so that it applies to the entire lg directory.

Also, you should type `sudo apache2 restart` to make the new changes come into effect.

Update: I think this is the config file you should be using:

```
#vi /etc/apache2/sites-available/default

Alias /lg/favicon.ico "/usr/local/httpd/htdocs/lg/favicon.ico"
    <Directory "/usr/local/httpd/htdocs/lg/favicon.ico">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

ScriptAlias /lg/  "/usr/local/httpd/htdocs/lg/"
        <Directory "/usr/local/httpd/htdocs/lg/">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128

        </Directory>
```

Notice that `/lg/`, which is a directory, points to `/usr/local/httpd/htdocs/lg/`, which is also a directory. The same thing applies to the `Directory` directive.

Then point your browser to `http://<host>/lg/lg.cgi`. Does this work?

Comment: I have edited my question. It will be `ScriptAlias /lg/  "/usr/local/httpd/htdocs/lg/lg.cgi"`, it's my mistake.

Comment: Wouldn't that redirect a directory to a file? I think `ScriptAlias /lg/ "/usr/local/httpd/htdocs/lg/"` would work better.

Comment: If I point my browser to `/lg/favicon.ico`, it shows the icon. But my main job is pointing to `lg`.

Comment: Do you want a directory listing when pointing your browser to /lg/?

Comment: my ultimate goal is to get a page  [like this](http://lg.version6.net/), from where I can ping, trace etc.

Comment: If you type http://<host>/lg, what do you expect to see?

Comment: To see a page [like this](http://lg.version6.net/)

Comment: I have edited my question. Try this version, type `sudo servie apache2 restart` and then point you browser to `http://<host>/lg/lg.cgi. What do you see, and what is the output of the command above?

Comment: It works but shows the content of `lg.cgi` file. Output is same as [this page](http://www.version6.net/lg/lg-1.9/lg.cgi), I am expecting like [this page](http://lg.version6.net/)

Comment: Try adding the line `AddHandler cgi-script .cgi`, like I've done above. Does this change anything?

Comment: `http://<host>/lg/`, output: `Forbidden`,
You don't have permission to access /lg/ on this server. `http://<host>/lg/lg.cgi`,`Internal Server Error`

Comment: It seems that the aliases are at least working. I would suggest trying to add the CGI scripts directly to a folder in the web root to make things easier. There is a tutorial here that explains the steps needed. It should work nicely. http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-apache2-webserver-with-phpcgi-and-perl-support-in-ubuntu-server.html